# Let $G$ be a group with $|G :Z(G)|=n$ ﬁnite. Let $A\subseteq G$. Show that the number of conjugates of $A$ is ﬁnite and divides $n.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

> Let $G$ be a group with $|G :Z(G)|=n$ ﬁnite. Let $A\subseteq G$. Show that the number of conjugates of $A$ is ﬁnite and divides $n.$

I know that  $G$ acts on the set of nonempty subsets of $G$ by conjugation.

I thought the orbit stabilizer theorem would be useful for an answer, but I can't use it well. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By conjugation, $G$ acts transitively on the set of conjugates of $A$.
For $g\in Z(G)$, the action is trivial, hence the action factors over $G/Z(G)$. Then orbit length divides $| G/Z(G)|$.